# Dropdown appears twice in PHP

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am implementing dropdown in themeforest AdminCC template using themeforest css,

the issue is when i applied dropdown, it appears twice instead of i implemented it once

And it automatically generates an extra dropdown at runtime that doesn't worth.

Whenever i tried to select any option from any of the dropdown, surprisingly both of them doesn't work and misbehaving too.

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
   <div class="form-group form-float">
     <div class="form-line">
     <select id="drop" class="form-control">
         <option value="Data1">Data1</option>
         <option value="Data2">Data2</option>
         <option value="Data3">Data3</option>
         <option value="Data4">Data4</option>
      </select>
      <label class="form-label">Block</label>
     </div>
    </div>
```

**Screenshot of dropdown**

[image]

**Console Code in Developer Tool**

```
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="drop" title="Data1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="filter-option pull-left">Data1</span>
    &nbsp;
      <span class="bs-caret">
        <span class="caret">
        </span>
      </span>
    </button>

    <select id="drop" class="form-control" tabindex="-98">
       <option value="Data1">Data1</option>
       <option value="Data2">Data2</option>
       <option value="Data3">Data3</option>
       <option value="Data4">Data4</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: drop down not appearing twice. looks like the css is collapsed.

Comment: even if i removed bootstrap-select.js and bootstrap-select.css also